# My shiny application on heroku timeout after 1 minute

Tags: r, docker, heroku, shiny, shinyapps

I've successfully launched my Shiny application on Heroku using a Docker image. The web application is up and running smoothly. Nevertheless, I encountered an issue where, upon opening the web app and simply scrolling without any interaction like clicking or hovering over charts, the screen turns gray after one minute of inactivity. Upon reviewing the logs, I discovered the "H15 timeout" error message. This timeout occurs after just one minute of inactivity on the page, which is inconvenient. Is there a way to extend the web server's timeout to at least 30 minutes?

This is the link to the web app: https://iec-risk-dashboard-a5582029f9d4.herokuapp.com/

This is my Docker file content:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
FROM rocker/r-ubuntu:18.04  
RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y tzdata
RUN ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York /etc/localtime
RUN dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y build-essential curl libssl1.0.0 libssl-dev gnupg2 software-properties-common dirmngr apt-transport-https apt-utils lsb-release ca-certificates
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
RUN add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/'
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y r-base

RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17 unixodbc-dev mssql-tools


RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    sudo \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    libcairo2-dev \
    libxt-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libssh2-1-dev \
    libgdal-dev\
    unixodbc\
    unixodbc-dev\
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN R -e 'install.packages(c(\
              "shinydashboard",  \
              "shinyjs", \
                "dplyr", \
                "stringr", \
                "sqldf", \
                "scales", \
                "DT", \
                "plyr", \
                "odbc", \
                "pool", \
                "shinydashboardPlus", \
                "waiter", \
                "feather" \
            ), \
            repos="https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/cran/__linux__/focal/2021-04-23"\
          )'

RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('echarts4r')"
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('highcharter')"
RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('formattable')"

RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('shiny')"


RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    sudo \
    libudunits2-dev \
    libgeos-dev \
    libproj-dev


RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('shinyWidgets')"

RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('waiter')"


RUN echo "local(options(shiny.port = as.numeric(Sys.getenv('PORT')), shiny.host = '0.0.0.0'))" > /usr/lib/R/etc/Rprofile.site

RUN addgroup --system app \
    && adduser --system --ingroup app app

WORKDIR /home/app

COPY app .


RUN chown app:app -R /home/app

USER app

EXPOSE 3838

CMD ["R", "-e", "shiny::runApp('/home/app')"]
```

Comment: https://tickets.dominodatalab.com/hc/en-us/articles/360058494751-Increasing-the-timeout-for-Shiny-Server   Is this helpful? Good looking app btw

Comment: Thank you Golem a lot. This works perfectly.